# Upgrade to Sonoma changed the resolution of screenshot action down to DPI of 72 (instead of 144). Any way it can be changed/fixed?

Tags: resolution, sonoma

Upgrade to Sonoma changed the resolution of screenshot action down to DPI of 72 (instead of 144). Any way it can be changed/fixed?

It appears that 'write com.apple.screencapture' action does not have DPI settings?

Comment: What resolution is your screen set to? If it's a non-Retina resolution the screenshot will be taken at 72 dpi. Retina displays double that, hence 144 dpi.

Comment: I can confirm that Sonoma captures screenshots at 144 pixels/inch on a 2021 MacBook Pro

Comment: I use Macbook pro  with retina resolution and had DPI of 144 prior to update. It appears that other folks have reported a similar problem (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738444). Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: So you are using the `screencapture` CLI, as shown in that link, not the Cmd-Shift-5 way? You might have made that clearer in the OP! Please update the OP to show how you are invoking the screenshot. Both mine & Ezekiel's confirmations are based on it working correctly using the UI method. However I can confirm that the CLI method does indeed produce 72 dpi images at any resolution in Sonoma. I can't comment to the past as it's not something I ever needed to do.

Comment: The DPI remains at 72 DPI whether I use screencapture CLI via terminal command or via Cmd-Shift-5, Cmd-Shift-3, Cmd-Shift-4.